# Bibliography name without cp1251[inputencod]

Tags: bibliographies

I make use only `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` in my TeX-preamble, i.e. without `\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}`. But why do I get in aux-files a stream of the cyrilic abrakadabra like `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{}{{\Russian  \CYRS \cyrp \cyri \cyrs \cyro \cyrk \ \cyrl \cyri \cyrt \cyre \cyrr \cyra \cyrt \cyru \cyrr \cyrery }}}{48}{section*.6}}`. At the same time, I've had a normal cyrilic text (without the Cyr's above) in all remaining contents lines. I would like just to do redefine something to fix this inconvenience. Redefinition of `\bibname` did not help.

Comment: Add a complete example. As it is your question is rather a mess.

Comment: Is there any inconvenience? I don't think so. Another question: is there any reason for using cp1251 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: My preamble is simple
`\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{amsart}`
`\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` `\begin{document}`. So corresponding aux-file looks nice except the Cyr-abrakadara line I displayed above. Also, sorry, I'm still living in a ASCII tex-editor, not UTF

Comment: I won't try to guess how you get your output. If you want an answer from me you will have to do your homework first and create a small but *complete* example which allows me to reproduce the problem. Don't put it in the comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: Even if you don't use `inputenc` but use pdfTeX (non-Unicode engine) `babel` defines localized strings (including "References") via `\cyr` macros. So, the only way to get rid of them is to switch to a Unicode engine like XeTeX or LuaTeX. (Or to redefine them by yourself.)

Comment: @Sergei Golovan. If I do right understand you the aux-file is created not only by LaTeX-standard `\tableofcontents` but (!) also by the Babel. The latter does make an addition like an entry corresponding to bibliography line in contents. If this is so then your answer is exhaustive. My thanks!